# Returning List of given argument type - java

Tags: java, generics

I have the following method

```
static <T> List<T> foo(List<T> arg) {
```

I want to create a List of the same type, call it `outcome`, as arg that I will eventually return. For example if

```
ArrayList<Integer> arg = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

I want foo to return an `ArrayList<Integer>` as well. 
If

```
LinkedList<Integer> arg = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

then I want foo to return a `LinkedList<Integer>`

I know `List<T> outcome = new List<T>();` will not work since List is abstract, so what am I suppose to write to do what I want?

Comment: `List<T> outcome = new ArrayList<T>();` ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What I mean is 'outcome' is the thing I'm going to eventually return. So I want 'outcome's type to be the same as arg's type

Comment: Why does it matter if you return an ArrayList or a LinkedList?

Comment: Just so that whoever is using the method will get back the same type they put in just in case they've implemented their code to use that type

Comment: The contract of your method is that it takes a list and returns a list. If the caller wants a LinkedList for the Deque methods, he can always write `LinkedList list = new LinkedList(foo(someList));`. I would not bother doing it in that method.

Comment: +1 for assylias. The whole point about interfaces is that you don't have to care about the underlying implementation.

Answer (score 4):

You can use reflection

```
List<T> list = (List<T>)arg.getClass().newInstance(); // throws
```

You can further constraint your method signature

```
static<L extends List<?>> L foo(L arg) { ... }


LinkedList<Integer> x = foo( new ArrayList<Integer>() ); // doesn't compile
```

Comment: that assumes that the class has a no-argument constructor that does what you want

Answer (score 3):

When you have a certain return type, *you can return any subclass of that return type*, so you can return an `ArrayList<T>`.

---

***EDIT (1)***: If you want to return a `List` of the same type as your argument, you could use `instanceof`:

```
static <T> List<T> foo(List<T> arg) {
    List<T> outcome = null;

    if (arg instanceof ArrayList)
        outcome = new ArrayList<T>();

    if (arg instanceof LinkedList)
        outcome = new LinkedList<T>();

    ...

    return outcome;
}
```

You can find a full list of the classes that implement `List` [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

---

***EDIT (2)***: Here's another idea:

```
static <T, U extends List<T>> U foo(U arg) {
    U outcome = arg;    
    ... 
    return outcome;
}
```

You might destroy the list you pass as `arg`, however, but you should be able to pass a copy.

Comment: I don't want to always return an ArrayList<T> though. If arg was a LinkedList<T>, then I want to return a LinkedList<T>

Comment: I see. Thanks. I guess there is no easy way then

Comment: are you going to add every class that implements List to your method?

Comment: I thought there would be a better way because I would really prefer not to lol

Comment: I can't destroy the arg list unfortunately, nor can I change the return type. Thanks though.

Comment: @user1529956 Then the `instanceof` method seems to be the only safe bet (at least that *I* can think of). You can use reflection, but it can be risky business in general, not sure how much so in this particular case.

Comment: There's an error in the sample code - `outcome` is null, so all the `instanceof` checks will fail - they should be `if (arg instanceof ...)`.  (I tried to make this as an edit, but it was rejected as an 'attempt to comment' or it 'changed too much of the original meaning')

Comment: There isn't a way to do what you're trying to do.  Really, you almost certainly shouldn't care how a `List` is actually implemented.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the excellent Google guava library. I think the Lists class there is something you need: 
http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v13.0.1/javadoc/index.html

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: I am not sure what's the author's intention to create this method and I believe he/she can leverage the google guava library for collection  features provided there.

Comment: If you are unsure what the question is asking for, you should post a comment (but you can't because you need a minimum reputation - that doesn't help!). Asnwers are supposed to be that: specific answers to the question. Finally, I don't think guava provides anything in the Lists utility class that would help solve the question.